# Comparar 2 diccionarios en python para crear otro diccionario con claves coincidentes

Tags: python

Estoy programando un desarrollo y quiero comparar 2 diccionarios, que en común tienen claves de igual nombre.

Por ejemplo diccionario 1 es de la forma:

```
    dic1 = {'0': [2.4636363650000002], '6': [4.1666666650000002], '9': [4.8333333349999998], '11': [3.5000000090000012], '14': [6.6181818249999989]}
```

El diccionario 2 es de la forma:

```
    dic2 = {'0': [2, 3, 4], '6': [5,6,7], '19': [4.8333333349999998], '10': [4.8333333349999998], '12': [3.5012]}
```

Al ver, el diccionario 2 coincide con el 1 las claves '0' y '6'.

Mi idea es crear un diccionario 3 que contenga solo esto:

```
    dic3 = {'0': [2, 3, 4], '6': [5,6,7]}
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es crear listas con las claves de cada diccionario, luego comparo estas listas y en el nuevo diccionario agrego aquellos elementos de las claves que coinciden. Quiero saber si ustedes conocen una forma más rápida y eficiente que recorrer y crear listas, ya que son muchas las claves que tengo.

Comment: Jorge, el elemento `{'10': [4.8333333349999998]` es también coincidente entre ambos diccionarios, fue un error o efectivamente no debería estar?

Comment: pero en el diccionario 3 no está la unión de los elementos coincidentes de los 2 diccionarios anteriores, creo que quedaría así:
`dic3 = {'0': [2, 3, 4, 2.4636363650000002], '6': [5,6,7, 4.1666666650000002], '10': [4.8333333349999998]}` a no ser que halla entendido mal la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Lo corregí gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hay un método muy sencillo usando *"compresiones de diccionarios"*:

```
dic3 = {k:v for (k,v) in dic2.items() if k in dic1}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dic3 = set(dic1).intersection(set(dic2))
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que esto **solo retorna las claves** presentes en ambos diccionarios, para obtener la salida que el OP quiere deberia hacerse algo como `dic3 ={key: dic2[key] for key in set(dic1) & set(dic2)}`. Si quieres puedes añadirlo a la respuesta para que quede completa. Saludos.

Comment: Ni siquiera hace falta `sets`. Sobra con combinar las *vistas* de claves : `dic3 = {k: dic2[k] for k in dic1.keys() & dic2.keys()} `

Answer (score 0):

Con un ciclo for puedes obtener la llave de cada elemento en el diccionario y recorrerlo.

```
for i in dic1:
   print i
   print dic1[i]
```

Comment: Juan, esto no responde la pregunta del OP

Comment: Si lo hace, el escribió: "Quiero saber si ustedes conocen una forma más rápida y eficiente que recorrer y crear listas" un ciclo es una opción.

Comment: Si te quedas solo con ese texto, tienes razón. Pero el OP esta ofreciendo un ejemplo del resultado que espera y habla de la comparación de dos diccionarios, de ahí mi comentario. Evidentemente entendimos cosas distintas. Saludos.